# Queue data structure implementation

Tags: c, arrays, date, queue, structure

I am currently trying to implement a queue data structure in C. The context is as follows:

A Doctors surgery needs a computer program to provide self-service to patients. Patients use this console to check in on arrivalto the surgery. They can also use the console to enquire about their position in the waiting list, or tofind out how many doctors are currently available at the surgery.The program is also used by doctors to check out (discharge) patients when they have finishedexamining them. Doctors use the program as well to check in and out of their rooms.The program must maintain a waiting list (queue) of all checked in patients, and as soon as one of thedoctors is free, the program must call on the next patient in the queue by displaying a message.

I need to implement the following queue functions:

```
void enqueue (int n) // append n to the queue
int dequeue () // remove the first item in the queue, and return its value
int first() // get the first item without removing it
int last () // get the last item without removing it
void clear () // clear (initialize) the queue
bool IsEmpty () // returns true if the queue is empty
bool IsFull () // returns true if the queue is full
void print () // print the entire queue
int position (int n) // returns the position of n in the queue, or -1 if n 
is not in the queue
void remove (int n) // remove n from the queue
```

The position function is something I'm struggling with a little bit:

```
int position(int n) {
  system("clear");
  int pos = 1;
  for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++) { // a for loop to run for each 
                                        // element in the queue
    if (queue[i % MAX] == n)  // checks to see whether the integer inputted 
                              // by the user is currently in the queue array    


  printf("Number %d is in the queue\n", num); //


  return;
    }
  }
```

I want the program to print out the position of n in the queue. I'm also not sure how to go about implementing a function to remove a specific element from the queue. Also I have yet to attempt the remove function, so will post again when I've done what I can to implement it.

I got the code to print the position in the queue, thanks to coderredoc! But because I want it to show the number 1, instead of 0 if something is first in the queue, I have used the following:

```
    void position(int n) {
      system("clear");
      int pos = 1;
      for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++) { 

        if (queue[i % MAX] == n)  
        printf("You are in the queue!\n"); 
        printf("Position in queue is %d \n",(i % MAX) +1);
            }
         }
```

but it loops and prints out more than once with increment positions in the queue. I know this is something to do with my for loop but not sure how to prevent it.

**EDIT: The above function has been fixed now. Thank you.**

Now to try and implement a function to remove an element defined by the user from the queue.

Comment: What are you having problem with? What is not working? Can you boil down the question to only be about the relevant functions, in the form of a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Remove anything that is not related to your actual problems.

Comment: OP edited to pinpoint where I need assistance the most

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in the code:-

**1.**

```
int position(int n) {
  system("clear");
  int pos = 1;
  for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++) { // a for loop to run for each 
                                        // element in the queue
    if (queue[i % MAX] == n)  // checks to see whether the integer inputted 
                              // by the user is currently in the queue array    


  printf("Number %d is in the queue\n", num); //


  return 0; <----------PROBLEM
    }
  }
```

Once the `if` is executed. Element not matched. And it returns.

**2.**

Also you use `num` but that is not changed when an element is found. Or atleast you should print the element  found.

**3.**

Also under `case 6:`

`scanf("%d, &id");` should be `scanf("%d", &id);`.

**4.**

Also in the `position()` function you don't `print` the right message.

`printf("Number %d is in the queue\n", num);` will be

`printf("Number %d is in the queue\n", n);`

**5.**

You are not using the returned value of `position()`. In case you don't need to return anything it should have a return type `void`.

#### How the code will be?

The funtion `position()` would be something like this

```
void position(int n) {
    system("clear");
    for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++) 
    { 

        if (queue[i % MAX] == n){
            printf("You are in the queue!\n"); 
            printf("Position in queue is %d \n",(i%MAX+1)-front);
            return;
        }  
    }
}
```

---

**Logical Error**

- Also in case more than 5 numbers entered, it drops elements silently without giving any message. Change that.
- Also the **logic of the queue implementation** is **wrong**. After you delete all the 5 elements it still shows both the message `queue` is full and `queue` is empty.

The algorithm you apply is still wrong. Check any book for that.

---

To help you a bit the queue *full* condition is

`(rear+1)%MAX == front`.

The queue *empty* condition is

`front == -1 && rear == -1`.  ( These holds for OP's implementation where `front= -1` and `rear = -1` initially).

#### Pseudocode for `insert()` would be:

```
1. if queue is full - show message.
2.    if queue is empty set front and rear to 0. [Denoting there is some element in queue]
3.    else rear = rear % MAX
4. put the element in the array at position rear.
```

#### Pseudocode for `delete()` would be:

```
1. if queue is empty - show message.
2. else if front == rear then rear = front = -1
3. else front = (front + 1)%MAX.
```

Comment: Thank you. I have managed to get it to print whether or not the nth element is in the queue but I'm not sure how to get it to print which position the nth element is in the queue, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working but have ran into another problem. I'll edit my post to show what it is.

Comment: Setting front and rear to 0 is causing the program to print the first element in the queue as zero when I chose the display queue option.

Comment: @GeorgeStrawbridge.: I have helped you with the basic idea and an algorithm for doing it. I mentioned you the problems. I will give you a hint here also...the loop will be something like `for(int i = 0; i<(rear+MAX-front)%MAX+ 1; i++) //print queue[(front+i)%MAX]` will print the queue. ...The next parts you can determine from here I guess...Try a bit now. It will help you.

Comment: @GeorgeStrawbridge.: Take a look at this site...and you will know how to ask questions etc. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction and bringing to my attention how I should ask questions in future.